# Use external scss file with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, next.js

I know this is a pretty recurrent question but I have a strange issue when I try to use an external scss file in my Nextjs app.

So I followed the instructions and installed `next-sass`, created a next.config.js at the root such as :

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
module.exports = withSass();
```

Then I import my scss file with `import '../style/home.scss'` in my component.

None of the styles applied to the classnames in that file are working. I got no errors showing up. 
 However when I target a html element such as `body` with `background-color: red` for example, it is working.

I'm fairly new to Nextjs, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you